# how can i go to the homescreen after i close the app, it directly takes me to the login page after i resrart the application

Tags: android, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging

```
  void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  AuthMethods().getCurrentUser();
  runApp(Chatterbox());
  }

  class Chatterbox extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  home: FutureBuilder(
    future:AuthMethods().getCurrentUser() ,
    builder:(context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic>snapshot)  {
      if(snapshot.hasData){
      return HomeScreen();}
      else{return WelcomeScreen();}
      } ),
   initialRoute: WelcomeScreen.id,
  routes: {
    WelcomeScreen.id:(context) => WelcomeScreen(),
    RegistrationScreen.id: (context) => RegistrationScreen(),
    LoginScreen.id :(context) => LoginScreen(),
    HomeScreen.id :(context) => HomeScreen(),

   },
   );
   }
    }
    // this is the method : 
   class AuthMethods   {
   final  FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

    //get current user
    getCurrentUser() async => auth.currentUser;
```

and these are the console messages:
Launching lib\main.dart on RMX1851 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk...
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:1428/EVkgGKsPCNs=/ws
Syncing files to device RMX1851...
I/ant.chatter_bo(27292): ProcessProfilingInfo new_methods=10 is saved saved_to_disk=1            resolve_classes_delay=5000

Comment: it was not working because i have defined the initial route as the welcome screen so as soon as deleted that it worked